# How to print specific data in a line

Tags: python, csv, separator, import-from-csv

My CSV file looks something like this (this is just an example):

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

How do I only get values 1,3 and 7 printed, without the rest?

Each line is separated by "." to print the full line.

Comment: _'Each line is separated by "." to print the full line.'_ What does this mean? There are no "." characters anywhere in your example.

Comment: You can look into the [`csv`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/csv) module of python.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```
>>> from csv import reader
>>> with open("test.csv") as f:
...     data = [(x[0], x[2], x[6]) for x in reader(f)]
...     
... 

>>> print(data)
[('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7'),
 ('1', '3', '7')]
>>>
```

Or if you just want to print the values while iterating:

```
>>> with open("test.csv") as f:
...     for row in reader(f):
...         print row[0], row[2], row[6]
...         
...     
... 
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
1 3 7
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from csv import reader
from operator import itemgetter

ig = itemgetter(0, 2, 6) # Remember index starts at 0

with open("data.csv") as fin:
    for row in reader(fin):
        print ig(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add a check to to see if the value is in the row.. or didn't know the placement in the row, then I would follow `msvalkon`'s answer editing it slightly:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for row in reader(f):
        get_text = lambda val: val+" " if row.find(',' + val + ',') >= 0 else ""
        print get_text("1") + get_text("3") + get_text("7")
```

This way the value:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9"
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

prints as:

```
1 3 7
1 7
1 3
3 7
```

instead of:

```
1 3 7
1 4 8
1 3 8
2 4 8
```